# Design approach cutting unnecessary api calls and storing data locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, local-storage

I am developing an iOS app with objective-C. With my 'GET' request am getting a large chunk of json data in below format.

> [ { @"value": @1,@"day":@2,@"hour":@1} , {@"value": @1,@"day":@1,@"hour":@1 }....]

Note, This array always contain 168 fixed number objects.

Inside my app I have different UI controls which suppose to show different chunks of the obtained data. For example clicking 'Button1' suppose to show ob1---obj10 and so on.

In theory its all working, but I am not happy with my design approach. 
Because for each button press I am calling the api to get the entire data set again and extracting the required data.

Ideally what I think should happen is I should store the data locally upon first 'GET' request and different classes within my app should be able to extract required information.

Same method should apply to my 'POST' requests. I am confused with what options I have, and what is best practice in this situation. I can think of following

1. Store data in an Array ?
2. Store the data in adatabase like sqlite ?
3. Finally plists ?
4. Using core data is bit of an overkill ?

Comment: Do you always receive fixed number of sub objects in your json or it is variable?

Comment: Knowing absolutely nothing about your API, it is hard to troubleshoot this. However, check if it supports pagination. If it does, then you should be able to break up your API calls into manageable chunks.

Comment: @FahedYasin fixed number.

Comment: @CodeBender question is more directed towards option available on app. I sure there is better way to store the data locally rather then calling the api all the time

Comment: So what is an object then? A few lines of text, an image, GIS data, etc? This plays a role in how to store it locally.

Comment: @CodeBender sorry about that, yes object is a simple dict @{@"value":@1 , @"day": @0, @"hour": 1} and I always get 168  if these fixed object in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

168 records where each is roughly 40 bytes gives about 7 Kb of data, which is probably reduced down to something like 2 Kb if your API server supports gzip compression. This is nothing according to modern web standards.

You could download it completely, parse and save to a variable in your view controller. I recommend creating a "model" class (as in [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) to wrap your data nicely and factor out the rows selection logic.

CoreData (or SQLite) is definitely an overkill for this amount of data.

You can use something like a plist or [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver?language=objc) to cache the data to disk if you need offline support, i.e. you want to have an app working without an internet connection.